# How to record data sent and received by specific program

Tags: networking, data-transfer

I am trying to capture data a program sends and receives from server during execution. The address of server also not known. How to do this?

can it be done by using fiddler or wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot realistically expect to capture the data sent to a server who's address you do not know. You would have to capture every piece of traffic and then wade through it all.

Also, you can only use Fiddler where you can place it between the client and the server since it acts as a proxy - in other words it sits between the client and the server & all traffic you want to record has to go through it.

The other issue you might get is if the connection between client and server is encrypted - e.g. using TLS (HTTPS). In such a case, you cannot capture the data unless you either have a way to capture it before it goes into the encrypted pipe (unlikely or you wouldn't be asking this question) or have a way to effectively perform a "man in the middle" attack with a proxy pretending to be the server (as far as the encryption is concerned).

On the other hand, wireshark works at the network layer so as long as you can create a "promiscuous" connection to your network (usually using a network driver called "pcap"). You need to know the start and end IP addresses of the conversation and again, an encrypted connection would make it useless.